# How to run join query in codenighter

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

hi i am new to codenighter frame work soome one can help me that how can i convert this join query to codenighter frame work and also told me that where i have to kept the join query i mean in model or controller..?
and how can i fetch the result of this query ..?
i want to pass the class_id as parameter..?

my query is here ..

```
SELECT e.roll,s.name,p.title,i.amount,i.amount_paid,i.status,i.creation_timestamp
FROM `payment` p
INNER JOIN student s    ON s.student_id=p.student_id
INNER JOIN enroll e     ON e.student_id=p.student_id 
INNER JOIN invoice i    ON i.student_id=p.student_id AND e.class_id=6 AND e.year="2016-2017"
```

Comment: You should really read the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/getting_started.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep this SQL query in your model and then pass the result to controller. You can pass the result set to controller from model and can use it from there. If you wan to pass it to view then you need to pass its data variable into view variable.

it should be like this,

In MODEL File:

```
    function get_data(){
        $this->db->select('enroll.roll,student.name,payment.title,invoice.amount,invoice.amount_paid,invoice.status,invoice.creation_timestamp');    
        $this->db->from('payment');
        $this->db->join('student', 'student.student_id = payment.student_id', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('enroll', 'enroll.student_id = payment.student_id', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('invoice', 'invoice.student_id = payment.student_id', 'inner');
        $this->db->where(array('enroll.class_id'=>6,'enroll.year'=>'2016-2017'));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            return $query->result_array();  
        }
    }
```

In CONTROLLER you can call this model function like this:

```
    $data['Data'] = $this->student_model->load_countries();
    $this->load->view('student_data',$data);
```

This is as per CodeIgniter active record framework. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use query method to write your own query .
in query method you can use joins easily 
for example

> Your Model

```
    class Model_name extends CI_Model {

                    function __construct()
                    {
                        parent::__construct();
                    }

                    public function get_record(){
                        $data  = $this->db->query('
                                   SELECT e.roll,s.name,p.title,i.amount,i.amount_paid,i.status,i.creation_timestamp
FROM `payment` p
INNER JOIN student s    ON s.student_id=p.student_id
INNER JOIN enroll e     ON e.student_id=p.student_id 
INNER JOIN invoice i    ON i.student_id=p.student_id AND e.class_id=6 AND e.year="2016-2017"
                                  ');
                        if($data->num_rows()>0){
                           return $data;
                        }
                   }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

**$this->db->join()** is helper funtion to perform join query

Permits you to write the JOIN portion of your query:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

// Produces:

```
// SELECT * FROM blogs JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
```

Multiple function calls can be made if you need several joins in one query.

If you need a specific type of JOIN you can specify it via the third parameter of the function. Options are: left, right, outer, inner, left outer, and right outer.

```
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id', 'left');
// Produces: LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
```

You can directly write query in the query() function too.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT e.roll,s.name,p.title,i.amount,i.amount_paid,i.status,i.creation_timestamp
FROM `payment` p
INNER JOIN student s    ON s.student_id=p.student_id
INNER JOIN enroll e     ON e.student_id=p.student_id 
INNER JOIN invoice i    ON i.student_id=p.student_id AND e.class_id=6 AND e.year="2016-2017"');
```

References: [CodeIgniter Docmentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Refer:-https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

You can also use below style:-
In MODEL File:

```
function get_data(){
$this->db->where(array('enroll.class_id'=>6,'enroll.year'=>'2016-2017'));
$this->db- >select('enroll.roll,student.name,payment.title,invoice.amount,invoice.amount_paid,invoice.status,invoice.creation_timestamp');    
$query = $this->db->from('payment')->join('student', 'student.student_id = payment.student_id', 'inner')->join('enroll', 'enroll.student_id = payment.student_id', 'inner')->join('invoice', 'invoice.student_id = payment.student_id', 'inner')->get();

if($query->num_rows()>0){
    return $query->result_array();  //You can also use result(); provide object array
}
```

}

In CONTROLLER you can call this model function like this:

```
 $data['Data'] = $this->student_model->load_countries();
 $this->load->view('student_data',$data);
```

In view you can get this with $data variable